# Ruby round() is rounding some numbers and not others

Tags: ruby, floating-point

I'm trying to keep two decimal points. I have numbers like:

```
9.96999.to_f.round(2)
```

and most of the time they're rounded to two decimal points (`9.97`), but occasionally I'll get one that looks like:

```
9.96999999999
```

Any ideas why?

**Edit**

I'm adding two values from a scraped table. Looking at the table, the only time this is happening is when the value from cell one is `9.02` and the value from cell two is `0.95`, or when the value from cell one is `9.87` and the value from cell two `0.1`. Both times I should obviously get `9.97`. Instead, I'm getting exactly `9.969999999999999`. All initial values start off as strings.

Comment: i tried 1000 times and i got `9.97` each time :s

Comment: Can you please give clear examples of both cases. ie: Code and values where one value is rounded to 2 decimal places, but the same code and different value that does not?

Comment: Just made an edit with more details.

Comment: Rather than rounding each separately, just round the sum. `(9.87 + 0.1).round(2)`

Comment: @HungryCoder, that worked. However, I just noticed that when the string starts off as something like `8`, and no value for the second cell, I end up with `8.0`. Anyway to force the second `0` when floating?

Comment: Use to_f. Like '(firstnum.to_f + secondnum.to_f).round(2)'

Answer (score 2):

Floating point values are inherently imprecise.  There is no exact representation for many exact decimal fractions. Even so, your round would work better if you performed it on the result of your calculation rather than its inputs.

Most likely you don't want round at all, but merely want to control presentation, in which case use [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) or [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25).

```
pry(main)> f = (9.02 + 0.95)
=> 9.969999999999999
pry(main)> '%.2f' % f
=> "9.97"
pry(main)> 9.02.round(2) + 0.95.round(2)
=> 9.969999999999999
pry(main)> f.round(2)
=> 9.97
```

It appears you have some fundamental misunderstanding of floating point representation and arithmetic. I suggest you read up on it before you get in trouble. Start here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the way floating point is handled by the system rather than Ruby.  As an example try this in IRB

```
10 - 8.2 - 1.8 #=> don't expect zero here
10 - (8.2 - 1.8) #=> same as above with a different result
```

Comment: For the first, I got `6.661338147750939e-16`. For the second, I got `3.6000000000000005`.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use .to_f.round()
Use this:
 A.round(2) -> anInteger

Which Rounds A to the nearest integer. (As simple as that)

Comment: I need two decimal places, though.

Comment: then multiply everything by 100, or use a [Rational](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Rational.html). Floating point numbers by definition are not precise.